# Expressing the gauge field strength tensor in terms of covariant derivatives of the vector potential

Tags: gauge-theory, covariance

Writing the [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative#Gauge_theory) as
$$ \tag{1} D_\mu = \partial_\mu -ig A_\mu $$
it is easy to show that (in the non-abelian case)
$$ \tag{2} [D_\mu,D_\nu] = -ig (\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu) -g^2 [A_\mu,A_\nu].$$
Using this expression we can define a [field strength tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_strength) $F_{\mu\nu}$ which generalizes the expressiong found in QED for abelian gauge-symmetries as
$$ \tag{3} F_{\mu\nu} \equiv \frac{i}{g} [D_\mu,D_\nu] = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu -ig[A_\mu,A_\nu]. $$

From the usual rule-of-thumb principle it seems that we should also be able to obtain this expression by making the substitution $\partial_\mu \rightarrow D_\mu$ in the "non-interacting" expression
$$\tag{4} F^{(0)}_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu. $$
However, how is the resulting expression
$$ \tag{5} F_{\mu\nu} = D_\mu A_\nu - D_\nu A_\mu$$
to be interpreted? In particular, if I consider the usual action of the covariant derivative on a field in the adjoint representation (call it $\alpha$),
$$ D_\mu \alpha \equiv \partial_\mu \alpha -ig [A_\mu,\alpha], $$
and use the fact that $A_\mu^a$ is in the adjoint representation, I get
$$ D_\mu A_\nu - D_\nu A_\mu = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu -2ig[A_\mu,A_\nu]$$
which is clearly off by a factor of 2. What is wrong in this resoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just confused about this myself, studying non-Abelian gauge theory for the first time (in many years).  So, even though this post is 4 years old, I will answer it to help others.

The problem with your calculation is that $A_\mu^a$ does not transform in the adjoint representation (or in any rep).  It is just not covariant at all, so there is no way to define a covariant derivative.  By contrast, $F_{\mu \nu}^a$ (defined with the commutator) does transform in the adjoint representation.

The reason this is confusing is because you often find statements to the effect that gauge fields do transform in the adjoint rep.  This is only true for *global* transformations ($\partial_\mu \alpha^a=0$).  But for global transformations there is no notion of a covariant derivative.

So, in summary, $D_\mu A^a_\nu$ is just not defined.